# Find missed period in SQL database records by perl script

Tags: perl

I am writing a script that checks if the database is complete. In the database SHOULD be records saved every minutes but I have some periods missed. The script must check do records / minutes are exists in database and print missed period (first and last missed minutes) in human date. I wrote something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $lock = 0;
my @empty;

#ZAKRES
my $dbtable = "USD_BCH";
my $dbh = DBI->connect(          
"dbi:SQLite:dbname=gekko/gdax-usd/history/gdax_0.1.db", 
"",                          
"",                          
{ RaiseError => 1 },         
) or die $DBI::errstr;
my $stmt = qq(SELECT start FROM candles_$dbtable ORDER BY start ASC LIMIT 1;);
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $stmt );
my $rv = $sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
if($rv < 0) {
  print $DBI::errstr;
}

my $start_all = $sth->fetchrow_array();

$stmt = qq(SELECT start FROM candles_$dbtable ORDER BY start DESC LIMIT 1;);
$sth = $dbh->prepare( $stmt );
$rv = $sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
if($rv < 0) {
  print $DBI::errstr;
}

my $end_all = $sth->fetchrow_array();

for (my $i = $start_all; $i < $end_all; $i += 60) {

#######


$stmt = qq(SELECT start FROM candles_$dbtable WHERE start LIKE $i ORDER BY start ASC LIMIT 1;);
$sth = $dbh->prepare( $stmt );
$rv = $sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
if($rv < 0) {
  print $DBI::errstr;
}
my $row;
$row = $sth->fetchrow_array();

if ($row) {
  if ($lock == 1) {
    my $firstempty = strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $empty[0];
    my $lastempty = strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", pop @empty;
    print "$firstempty-$lastempty\n";
    $lock = 0;
  }
#print "Pełne: $row\n";
}
else {
  $lock = 1;
  push @empty, $i;
#print "Pueste: @empty\n";
}

}
if ($lock == 1) {
  my $firstempty = strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $empty[0];
  my $lastempty = strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", pop @empty;
  print "$firstempty-$lastempty\n";
  $lock = 0;
}
```

Its example database records:

```
1523182500
1523182560
1523182620
1523182680
1523182740
1523182800
1523182860
1523182920
1523182980
1523183040
1523183100
1523183160
1523183220
1523183280
1523183340
1523183400
1523183460
1523183520
1523183580
1523183640
1523183700
1523183760
1523183820
1523183880
1523183940
1523184000
1523184060
1523184120
1523184180
1523184240
1523184300
1523184360
1523184420
1523184480
1523184540
1523184600
1523184660
1523184720
1523184780
1523184840
1523184900
1523184960
1523185020
1523185080
1523185140
1523185200
1523185260
1523185320
1523185380
1523185440
1523185500
1523185560
1523185620
1523185680
1523185740
1523185800
1523185860
1523185920
1523185980
1523186040
1523186100
1523186160
1523186220
1523186280
1523186640
1523186700
1523186760
1523186820
1523186880
1523186940
1523187000
1523187060
1523187120
1523187180
1523187240
1523187300
1523187360
1523187420
1523187480
1523187540
1523187600
1523187660
1523187720
1523187780
1523187840
1523187900
1523187960
1523188020
1523188080
1523188140
```

The problem is that the tables in my database are very large (up to 100 MB). The above script is not very efficient, it takes up to 1 hour to check! What solution do you recommend that data validation takes less time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have obviously tried to decompose the problem into subtasks but that have gone awry because you apparently didn't encounter an example of a gap checking algorithm before.
Consider reading some book on algorithms, not necessarily in Perl, it will really help.

In the end you've got  a lot of unnecessary code and excess database calls so no wonder it is slow as hell.

A much shorter code doing the same:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

#ZAKRES
my $dbtable = "USD_BCH";
my $dbh = DBI->connect(          
"dbi:SQLite:dbname=gekko/gdax-usd/history/gdax_0.1.db", 
"",                          
"",                          
{ RaiseError => 1 },         
) or die $DBI::errstr;


my $stmt = qq(SELECT start FROM candles_$dbtable ORDER BY start ASC;);
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $stmt );
my $rv = $sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
my $fmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';
my $expected;
while (my @row=$sth->fetchrow_array())  {
  if (defined $expected && $row[0] != $expected) {
    printf "%s - %s\n", strftime($fmt, localtime $expected), strftime($fmt, localtime ($row[0]-60))
  }
  $expected=$row[0]+60
}
```

Comment: WOW! Its really fast and really smart! Im hobbyst, not professional coder. Im still learning. Can You recommend some sources about algorithms simillar to Your solution?

Comment: Its working good but I dont understand why script print period date only one time. $row[0] != $expected is "true" more than one time... Can You explain how it work? How it get end date of period?

Comment: I can see only one gap in your data: from `1523186280` to `1523186640`. Why do you think the condition is true more than once? Is there something else that I am not seeing?

Comment: @F.Grela Sorry, I can't recommend any specific book or resource. The idea is much too simple so I doubt it would be addressed specifically by a book. Just find some introductory book on algorithms with examples (there are lots of questions about that in the internet). Read through problems and solutions and think how you could have approached them. That should teach you quickly to spot non-optimal code.  
Perhaps if examples were in C that would be better because with C one have to be smart about data structures and everything else (not like Perl where a developer can be too relaxed).

Comment: But its true every one minute in this period. I dont understand how script print only start and end period...

Comment: @F.Grela because the data in the database does not have records for every minute in a gap, it only has the start and the end records for a gap. See?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the speed problem is coming from the fact that you're fetching one record per loop iteration, when you could be fetching everything in one SQL statement. Also, I'm not entirely sure how correct your code is:

- I get a usage error from `POSIX::strftime` because you're passing it a UNIX timestamp, I have to send that through `localtime` first for it to work.
- When you print your gaps, you're printing `$empty[0]` as the start time, but you never empty the `@empty` array, so if there are multiple gaps in the data you always print the same start time for every gap.

I was about to post an example solution, but @wolfrevokcats beat me to it ☺ So let me just add that [wolfrevokcats's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49718580/9300627) finds the same gap in your sample data as your code, and on larger data (9000 rows) [it runs roughly x2000 faster](https://gist.github.com/haukex/a18a3021f139ce5317dc987e2c821fcb) (at least on my machine).